# wx.listctrl focus imprcise

Tags: wxpython, focus, listctrl

dear all:

I am using list ctrl in a wxPython Frame.

```
self.listCtrl = wx.ListCtrl(self.framePanel, size=wx.DefaultSize, 
    style = wx.LC_REPORT | self.styleGiven | wx.BORDER_SUNKEN | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL 
)
```

I have 80 items in the list ctrl.
Then I want to set focus on a selected item with the self.listCtrl.Focus() method.
The method works for small values of item index.
But for larger values of item indices, self.listCtrl.Focus() the method gradually loses focus precision.
For example, if I do self.listCtrl.Focus(15), then the top item row in the view is actually with index 17.
When I call

```
self.listCtrl.Focus(60)
```

The top item row in the view is actually with index 64.
Can someone show me how to do this correctly?

Thank you very much.

Farn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not convinced that `SetFocus` is fundamentally different from `EnsureVisible`, which simply ensures that the list has been scrolled sufficiently, to ensure that item is visible.
Try `self.listCtrl.Select(60)` in tandem with `self.listCtrl.Focus(60)` so that the item you require is obvious.
p.s. Remembering that the listctrl items are Zero based.

If that fails, ensure that you really do have all the items in the list, that you think you have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Yes, doing Select and Focus in tandem indeed solves the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to get the selected item as high as possible in the visible list do `EnsureVisible`for the last row first and then for the actual one

Comment: It's clear what you are suggesting to do, but the asker might not understand how you're answer can resolve the issue. Perhaps you can clarify that by calling EnsureVisible for the last row first, it will ensure that the selected item will potentially come into view. However, on long enough lists - this might not be the case; so keep that in mind as well and perhaps give attention to that to avoid downvotes from members who might identify that the answer might not resolve the problem the asker is asking to have resolved.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes at all as long as I have seen it works: I have a Windows and a list with 502 entries; the visible part is 19 and if the chosen entry is not in the last 19 lines of the list it will be displayed at the top position; otherwise the last 19 lines are displayed and the chosen entry somewhere on the screen - as far as know it's impossible to get the chosen entry always to the top, that's why I said 'as high as possible': it does not depend on wx but rather on the underlying desktop list control - if you know more I'm very interested and would be please to hear of it..

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of the list having enough entries that the item they want is out of view with - let's say - an indice of 100. You suggest taking the *last* index and  calling `EnsureVisible` on it,  which should scroll to bring *that* item into view - leaving items above it potentially within the view too; Item at index 100 is now not necessarily visible because the last indice was 1000, and it being visible made indice 900 the first item visible.  If this type of circumstance isn't possible - you should clarify that, because the typical perception wouldn't assume that.

Comment: what I said was pretty simple: if you have a list of len(list) = x and you want to position to row r (zero based index!) then just insert EV(x) and EV(r) (if the screen flickers, which I doubt, there are remedies)

Comment: Silly me, late night trying out the `first answer reviews` feature that was just unlocked for me (its essentially homework, helping ensure first time answers meet community guidelines). I was too focused on the result of calling `EnsureVisible` on the last row, and how that doesn't guarantee to show the intended item at the top, nor at all; you do suggest to call it again though, which does in cases intended item goes beyond - though this isn't the right focus; I should have suggested you please explain how this would work for all cases for asker to resovlve their issue. I apologize for that.